# Shutdown.target in conflict with other services at the boot process?

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown, services

A few days ago, I started an investigation about why my laptop is taking so much time to boot. My laptop details:
Lenovo Y480
Intel® Core™ i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8
8GB RAM
Ubuntu 16.04 (recently upgraded)

First at all, I've run `systemd-analyze blame`, giving me next information:

```
     13.767s winbind.service
     13.754s nmbd.service
     13.499s samba-ad-dc.service
     11.526s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     11.394s dev-sda6.device
      9.032s apparmor.service
      8.219s NetworkManager.service
      8.087s accounts-daemon.service
      7.318s gpu-manager.service
      6.158s snapd.refresh.service
      6.134s user@1000.service
      5.037s grub-common.service
      4.362s console-setup.service
      4.070s thermald.service
      3.813s networking.service
      3.745s console-kit-log-system-start.service
      3.739s systemd-user-sessions.service
      3.608s systemd-udevd.service
      3.197s lightdm.service
      2.973s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.708s bluetooth.service
      1.772s irqbalance.service
      1.570s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.551s vboxdrv.service
      1.451s keyboard-setup.service
      1.344s rsyslog.service
      1.308s udisks2.service
      1.307s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.303s systemd-journald.service
      1.244s colord.service
      1.219s binfmt-support.service
```

As you can see there are so many services that are taking more than 1 second.

After that, I've executed the command `systemd-analyze dot` giving me a lot of information. Due the extension of that information, I am not leaving here a copy. But using graphviz software and compiling all matches of `shutdown.target` service, I saw it is "in conflict" with a lot of services. I am not an advanced user, I am quite noob on these things. I supose they are in conflict because on "color references", says:

```
   Color legend: black     = Requires
             dark blue = Requisite
             dark grey = Wants
             red       = Conflicts
             green     = After
```

As I can understand, red means conflicts among these services. I've generated a png graphic in order to see in a better way the result of `systemd-analyze dot` command.

[The picture shows A lot of services are "in conflict" with shutdown.target. Am I right? How can I solved without reinstall ubuntu?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQW4w.jpg)